# I have some issue on new php version i am used PHP Version 5.3.29 and now using PHP Version 5.4.45 or greater

Tags: php, escaping

I have some issue on new php version i am used  PHP Version 5.3.29  and now using  PHP Version 5.4.45  or greater

question is

escape  in mysql not working in new version so any change to replace
mysql_real_escape_string

means escape to mysql_real_escape_string  globally.

please help me.

Comment: stop using mysql_* = problem solved

Comment: not understand , how i can use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `mysqli_real_escape_string` `mysql` functions are deleted and no longer can be available.

Comment: dont use mysql_* use mysql**i**_*

Comment: but i am using escape  so i want to replace that  on new version and escape are many time used so any other solutions where i set replace with mysqli_real_escape_string ok

Comment: there is no way to use mysql_real_escape_string use mysqli